# How can I use remmina to connect to a Windows Server?

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I have all this information to connect to a windows exchange server at work, but I don't know where to enter it in **Remmina** as it has different fields, with different names. The windows-screens give met the following.

```
General-tab: a computer name and A user-name consisting of probably a domainname\username
View-tab: The screen has to be set at 32bits and full-size
Local sources:tick support of smart-cards, gates, stations and other PnP.
Advanced-tab: make a connection and don't warn me.
```

And when I push the settings button I have to enter the following:

```
Use these settings to use remote desktop. server-name: rds.name.org connection-method: Ask for password(NTLM). 
tick the box at don't use local addresses for remote desktop gateway-server. 
and tick the box at the bottom: use my remote desktop gateway-references for my remote computer.
```

I got all this info from my work to make a remote desktop connection from a windows machine. As usual they think there are no other OS users. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

It's a blind shot, as I don't know the exact configuration of your work server, but a common problem:

In the advanced tab, on security type, choose RDP:

[image]

In the user field, put the domain/user pair.

Comment: If you go to Basic section, There is already a field for Domain so we don't really need to user domain/user format in username field

Comment: Did you test it?. It used to be "DNS Domain", I had always assumed (likely incorrect) that it was not related to windows domains.